# Using different version of jquery on different ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am currently working in **NOPCommerce 3.0** site which is currently using **JQuery 1.7**. All of its pages have dependency on that. in the site I have created a section which i have created using **JQuery 2.0**  (that part is not supported in 1.7 so i have to use 2.0). So now how can i change the reference so that My partial View use JQuery 2.0 instead JQuery 1.7

I already put script tag to create another reference but it just give me errors due to JQuery Conflicting in the try

Comment: Can you please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>


Then, instead of 
$('#selector').function();, you'd do jQuery_1_3_2('#selector').function(); 
or jQuery_1_1_3('#selector').function();
```